# Java Regex - Trying to isolate text from a line that starts with a certain string?

Tags: java, android, regex

**EDIT: MAKE SURE YOU CALL Matcher#matches or Matcher#find before trying to use group!**
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776826/question-about-java-regex)

---

I'm trying to do something very simple - I'm trying to get the text from a line that starts with a word. In this case, the word is `Location:`. I'm reading from raw HTML so the line of interest actually looks like this:

```
      Location: Main Hall
```

Obviously, I want `Main Hall` returned to me so I can read the location for my application.

This is what I've tried:

```
String t_location = "";
Pattern t_pat = Pattern.compile("^[\\s]+?(?s)Location: (?-s)(.*)$");
Matcher t_match = t_pat.matcher(t_inner_html);
t_location = t_match.group(0);
```

But I keep getting the error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far`

Breaking down my Regex, this is what (I think) I'm doing:

`^` - Read from the beginning of the line

`[\\s]+?` - With a reluctant qualifier, read the whitespace at the beginning of the line until we hit something else

`(?s)Location: (?-s)` - The literal string "Location: " is read

`(.*)$` - Read characters (except newlines) until the end of the line

That is what I **THINK** I'm doing. I'm not so good at Regex, but I've tried to follow the documentation to no avail. Can someone please help me?

---

For example purposes, the String `t_inner_html` looks like this:

```
8/28/2014
      Alumni Reunion
      Location: Main Hall

      <span class="extra-info">
           Blah blah blah....
      </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were not Java, this regex should work, depending on what your end-of-line (EOL) character sequence is:

```
(.|\n)*Location:\s*(.*)\n
```

The string you want is at group index `1`.

Now since this regex is going to be inside a Java `String`, and since backslashes are escape characters in Java strings, you will actually have to pollute the pure regex with double backslashes:

```
Pattern t_pat = Pattern.compile("(.|\\n)*Location:\\s*(.*)\\n");
```

In general, to test regexes, I really like this tool:

http://regexpal.com/

It's an interactive tester that will progressively highlight your sample input as it matches the regex. When you edit the regex or change the sample input, the matching highlighting will update in real time. This does not support the required double backslashes of Java, so test in the tool with the singles, paste them to Java, and then add the extra backslashes.

You may also want to play around with this tool, which is not as real-time but does support Java `String` regexes:

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

To break down what I have:

`(.|\n)*` - zero or more characters or EOL sequences

`Location:` - the string "Location:"

`\s*` - zero or more white space

`(.*)` - a regex group consisting of absolutely anything, which is what you will capture

`\n` - EOL sequence

You may need to replace `\n` with `\r\n` if you are on Windows, but try `\n` first and see.

This will match everything in your sample input through "Main Hall", and will ignore everything after (`<span . . .>` etc.)  "Main Hall" will end up in the match group `1`.

Comment: I have a feeling that this should work, but it does not.

Comment: Is your input text just the line "Location: Main Hall", or is it that entire block beginning with "8/28/2014"?  If the latter, then you are now matching against multiple lines rather than a single one, and it is a somewhat different story.

Comment: Yeah, it's multiple lines, `t_inner_html` is what I'm looking at. I tried your expression with the `(?m)` flag prepended.

Comment: I had to call `t_match.matches()` first ._.

Comment: That's right - sorry I was more focused on the regex itself than the Java API.  Glad it is working - thanks for accepting the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
    String t_location = "";
    Pattern t_pat = Pattern.compile("^\\s+Location:\\s+(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher t_match = t_pat.matcher(t_inner_html);
    if (t_match.find()) {
       t_location = t_match.group(1);
    }
```

You need to use [Pattern.MULTILINE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) for the expressions ^ and $ to match each line instead of the whole string.

---

[Java Fiddle Demo](http://java-fiddle.com/#code=import+java.util.regex.Pattern%3B%0Aimport+java.util.regex.Matcher%3B%0A%0Apublic+class+ClassNameHere+%7B%0A++++public+static+void+main(String%5B%5D+args)+%7B%0A++++++++String+t_inner_html+%3D+%228/28/2014%5Cn%22+%2B%0A+++++++++++%22++++++Alumni+Reunion%5Cn%22+%2B%0A+++++++++++%22++++++Location%3A+Main+Hall%5Cn%22+%2B%0A+++++++++++%22%5Cn%22+%2B%0A+++++++++++%22++++++%3Cspan+class%3D%5C%22extra-info%5C%22%3E%5Cn%22+%2B%0A+++++++++++%22+++++++++++Blah+blah+blah....%5Cn%22+%2B%0A+++++++++++%22++++++%3C/span%3E+%22%3B%0A++++++++String+t_location+%3D+%22%22%3B%0A++++++++Pattern+t_pat+%3D+Pattern.compile(%22%5E%5C%5Cs%2BLocation%3A%5C%5Cs%2B(.*)%24%22,+Pattern.MULTILINE)%3B%0A++++++++Matcher+t_match+%3D+t_pat.matcher(t_inner_html)%3B%0A++++++++if+(t_match.find())%0A+++++++++++t_location+%3D+t_match.group(1)%3B%0A+++++++%0A++++++++System.out.println(t_location)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D&mode=edit&showStringsAsObjects=)

Comment: This is also a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

First use String indexOf Method to find wether line contains "Location :".
Then use str.replace("Location : ",""); on the line which has "Location :".

Answer (score 0):

```
 .*?Location:(.*?)\n
```

This should get you what you want.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rJ1oQ3/1